# Can't loop through the values of a subset of vectors in R

Tags: r, function, aggregate

I apologize if the question is really basic, I'm still a complete newbie with R.

In my data set, observations come from people who were asked how satisfied they were on a scale from 1 to 10, each month during a period of 6 months.

There was no obligation to participate, so sometimes they answer, sometimes they don't.

I am trying to build a variable that counts how many times they answered the question. I consider that they answer it if the answer is >0.

So first I selected the relevant variables from my dataset and stored them into a separate dataframe (don't pay attention to the "average" in the name, for the purpose of the question just consider it's their single answer for the month):

```
monthly_sats <- select (donnees, average_satisfaction_march, average_satisfaction_april, 
                        average_satisfaction_may, average_satisfaction_june, 
                            average_satisfaction_july, average_satisfaction_august)
```

Then, I created a variable where I would store how many times (so, how many months) each person answered, and I initialized it to 0.

```
donnees$monthly_sat_count <- 0
```

So far so good. Then, I wrote the following:

```
for (i in monthly_sats) {
  for(j in i) {
    if (j > 0) {
      donnees$monthly_sat_count <- donnees$monthly_sat_count + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I meant:
for each variable in the monthly_sats data frame
for each value in these variables
if that value is greater than 0, increase the monthly_sat_count variable from the "donnees" data set by 1.

I expected that, for each line in my dataset, monthly_sat_counts would tell how many of these variables were greater than 0.

And the result is that every single line of monthly_sat_counts is equal to 365, and I have no idea why.

Note that I also tried subsetting instead of selecting, and the result is exactly the same. Here is the code:

```
for (i in donnees[c("average_satisfaction_march", "average_satisfaction_april",
                        "average_satisfaction_may", "average_satisfaction_june",
                            "average_satisfaction_july", "average_satisfaction_august")]) {
  for(j in i) {
    if (j > 0) {
      donnees$monthly_sat_count <- donnees$monthly_sat_count + 1
    }
  }
}
```

And if I remove the second for loop, simply looping through the list of vectors with the code below, then monthly_sat_count is always equal to 0:

```
for (i in donnees[c("average_satisfaction_march", "average_satisfaction_april",
                    "average_satisfaction_may", "average_satisfaction_june",
                        "average_satisfaction_july", "average_satisfaction_august")]) {
  if (i > 0) {
    donnees$monthly_sat_count <- donnees$monthly_sat_count + 1
}
```

I have no idea why it does that, and I don't even know where to begin in debugging because I still have trouble understanding R. My only programming background was a little C# some time ago.

Anyway, if sometimes could explain me why it doesn't work and show me a better way of doing it, it would really make my day !

Comment: there is likely a much easier way to do it. if you explain the structure of your data it would be easier to suggest an approach. do you just have a data.frame where rows are individuals and columns are monthly responses?

Comment: Yes, that's it, sorry. But Len's answer did the trick, it works now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0:10), 60, TRUE), ncol = 6))
colnames(df) <- wrapr::qc(average_satisfaction_march, average_satisfaction_april, 
               average_satisfaction_may, average_satisfaction_june, 
               average_satisfaction_july, average_satisfaction_august)

df$donnees <- c(1:10)
df <- df[,c(7,1:6)] 

df$timesanswered <- apply(df[,2:7], 1 , function(x) {length(x[x>0])})
```

At first I created some sample data. The last line is the code to count the times per donnee satisfaction is not zero in a month. I assumed the way you described your data you have no missing values, but zeroes are filled in when a donnee did not answer the question?

You could replace the 2 and 7 with the column numbers of average_satisfaction_march and average_satisfaction_august, respectively. There is no need to create a separate data frame to do this.

Comment: You assumed correctly (and I should have specified it, sorry). And that worked, thank you very much for your help !